# Installing OpenStack Kilo in a modern OS

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I'm trying to run a legacy code written for **OpenStack Kilo**, in order to migrate it to newer versions of OpenStack.
I mostly need Nova, Neutron and Placement of that version in order to test the code.

So far, I tried to install Kilo using RDO on Fedora 33 (there was no DevStack of Kilo) using `packstack` from the rpm:
`rdo-release-kilo-2.noarch.rpm` from [here](https://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/openstack/EOL/openstack-kilo/), but running:

`rpm –iv rdo-release-kilo-2.noarch.rpm`

and then:

`(sudo) dnf install openstack-packstack`

I get the error:

`Error: Faild to download metadata for repo "openstack-kilo" : Cannot download repond.xml ... All mirrors were tried`

I guess that since Kilo is at End-Of-Life status, the repository isn't alive. However, in order to test the original code (which is heavily depended on the fact it was written for versions Kilo and older) I really need to get a working installation of OpenStack of that version.

Is there any way to install it on a VM these days? (preferably a simple installation since I don't need a fancy configuration of OpenStack).

Comment: The Centos vault allows you to install old versions of Centos, such as 7.2, and Kilo is there as well: https://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/cloud/x86_64/. I also see Packstack, much simpler method than manually setting up the cloud from RPMs  You will have to doctor the /etc/yum.repos.org files and redirect them to the vault repos.

Comment: @berndbausch Do I need to add the repos to a need section within the `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` ? Should I replace all to point to the vault? (I'm getting a lot of `error 404` running `yum update`)

Comment: More specifically `https://valut.centos.org/7.2.1551/<place>/<path>: HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found`

Comment: This is how I managed to install Newton on Centos 7.3 some time ago (both were beyond end of support): After installing the OS from the ISO file, remove `mirrorlist` directives, and enable `baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1551/os/$basearch`. Then `yum update`. Disable firewall and NetworkManager, then `yum install
centos-release-openstack-kilo`.

Comment: After that, tweak the new repo files again, replacing the normal URLs with the vault. For example `# sed -i '/^baseurl/s%mirror.centos.org/centos/[^/]*%vault.centos.org/7.2.1551%' CentOS-OpenStack-newton.repo CentOS-Ceph-Jewel.repo CentOS-QEMU-EV.repo`. The result should look like `baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1551/cloud/$basearch/...`. After that, install `openstack-packstack`. Note that the above instructions are based on my old Newton+Centos7.3 instruction, where I just replaced Newton with Kilo and 7.3 with 7.2. In other words, it may or may not work.

Comment: I faintly remember problems with `qemu` at an earlier iteration of my attempts, but I have no clear recollection and don't find the corresponding files.

Comment: @berndbausch I didn't get the idea with the `OpenStack-newton.repo`, `CentOS-Ceph-Jewel.repo` and `CentOS-QEMU-EV.repo`. I am now trying to get `mitaka` running (newer than Kilo, and may work). Where do you add this?

Comment: The above `grep` command was my solution to point the `baseurl` clauses in the repo files to the vault site, since the original sites are not available anymore. What do you mean by your last sentence?

Comment: @berndbausch The `# sed -i '/^baseurl/s%mirror.centos.org/centos/[^/]*%vault.centos.org/7.2.1551%' CentOS-OpenStack-newton.repo CentOS-Ceph-Jewel.repo CentOS-QEMU-EV.repo` what is the part in the end?

Comment: At the end, there are three repo files that were added by `yum install centos-release-openstack-newton`.

Comment: @berndbausch Have you encountered an issue with `Could not resolve host: vault.centos.org` in `yum update` after changing the mirrorlist in the new repo files?

Comment: Is your DNS set up correctly? `ping vault.centos.org`?